# How to change LaTex equation tag style

Tags: latex

I am currently working on my essay and trying to use LaTex to finish my work.

I got equation tags style like `(2.1)` and `(2.2)` , and I am asked to change them into style like `(2-1)` and `(2-2)`. I have difficulty in finding relevant articles or answers.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to the community.

I found an approach in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61756/how-to-change-equation-numbering-style)

Add this to `.cls` file.

```latex
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter--\arabic{equation}}
```